# Pandas groupby: Replace values in one column before the first occurrence in another column

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

Below is a toy Pandas dataframe that has three columns: 'id' (group id), 'b' (for condition), and 'c' (target):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 
              'b'  : [3,4,5,'A',3,4,'A',1,'A',1,3,'A',2,3], 
              'c'  : [1,0,1,10,1,1,20,1,10,0,1,20,1,1]})
print(df)
    id  b   c
0    1  3   1
1    1  4   0
2    1  5   1
3    1  A  10
4    1  3   1
5    1  4   1
6    1  A  20
7    2  1   1
8    2  A  10
9    2  1   0
10   2  3   1
11   2  A  20
12   2  2   1
13   2  3   1
```

For each group, I want to replace the values in column 'c' with nan (i.e., `np.nan`) before the first occurrence of 'A' in column 'b'.

The desired output is the following:

```
desired_output_df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 
                                  'b'  : [3,4,5,'A',3,4,'A',1,'A',1,3,'A',2,3], 
                                  'c'  : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,10,1,1,20,np.nan,10,0,1,20,1,1]})
print(desired_output_df)
    id  b     c
0    1  3   NaN
1    1  4   NaN
2    1  5   NaN
3    1  A  10.0
4    1  3   1.0
5    1  4   1.0
6    1  A  20.0
7    2  1   NaN
8    2  A  10.0
9    2  1   0.0
10   2  3   1.0
11   2  A  20.0
12   2  2   1.0
13   2  3   1.0
```

I am able to get the index of the values of column c that I want to change using the following command: `df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.loc[:(x.b == 'A').idxmax()-1]).index`. But the result is a "MultiIndex" and I can't seem to use it to replace the values.

```
MultiIndex([(1, 0),
            (1, 1),
            (1, 2),
            (2, 7)],
           names=['id', None])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example seems to contradict your description. Why `c` of row 7 is `NaN` in your desired output?

Comment: In the group with id = 2, row 7 represents the instance before the first occurrence of "A" in column b.

Comment: Oh, ok! I overlooked the "for each group" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df['c'] = np.where(df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['b'].eq('A').cumsum()) > 0, df['c'], np.nan)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    id  b     c
0    1  3   NaN
1    1  4   NaN
2    1  5   NaN
3    1  A  10.0
4    1  3   1.0
5    1  4   1.0
6    1  A  20.0
7    2  1   NaN
8    2  A  10.0
9    2  1   0.0
10   2  3   1.0
11   2  A  20.0
12   2  2   1.0
13   2  3   1.0
```